# ViewPager with Parallax effect

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-animation, parallax

I wanted to created **ViewPager with Parallax effect in which will be indicator.** I am just beginner so i tried to use this library form GitHub https://github.com/prolificinteractive/ParallaxPager

I did everything by instruction, but it didn't work. Can anyone explain me how to do it?

**1.** I added this project to my project.

**2.** I Used a ParallaxContainer in my main layout XML.

**3.** For each page i created new layout XML files as in instaction. I added this line for each of them  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" , but its mistake everywhere in which was word app. app:x_in="@dimen/parallax_speed_slow" etc. Mistake was like "Unexpected namespace prefic app found for tag ImageView"

**4.** Find the parallax container by ID, Specify whether the pager should loop (true means it will loop),Submit a Layout Inflater and list the layouts for each page (in order). Currently there must be at least 2 in this list (repeats allowed).

**5.** In this Activity i added this method attachBaseContext to as in instaction

At the end when i test it in emulatore nothing happened. What i missed to do. What`s wrong here? Another problem is indicator as you see. Can anyone show me how to make parallax effect in viewpager or you have another good examples?

Comment: instead of using external libs create your custom background Drawable that implements your parallax effect and call setBackground on your view pager

Comment: @pskink Sure, but can you give me an example?

Comment: class ParallaxDrawable extends Drawable {... @override draw(Canvas canvas) {...